# node.js: after giving absolute path, it prints entire js instead of loading website

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, jwt

I am using node js for my project where i am using apple map for the project. So I have setup apple map and the code was working in live environment but failed while setting up on local.

This is my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 16000

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile('/support.js')
})
app.get('/services/jwt',(req,res) => {

  const header = {
    "alg": "code",
    "typ": "JWT",
    "kid": "code"
  }

  const payload = {
    "iss": "code",
    "iat": Date.now() / 1000,
    "exp": (Date.now() / 1000) + 15778800,
  }

  var cert = fs.readFileSync('./AuthKey_keyT.p8'); // private key that you downloaded
  var token = jwt.sign(payload,cert, { header: header } );
  res.json({token: token})
})

app.listen(PORT,(req,res) => {
  console.log("Server has started...")
})
```

first error i got was

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/support.js'

so i change the path to absolute

```
  res.sendFile('support.js',{root:__dirname+"/public/others/"})
```

after this when i rerun the node and hit the url i am getting support.js printed on the screen. Unable to load the website. Not sure what is wrong.

have rendered it through httpd

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName website.domain.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
        <Location "/">
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                ProxyPass http://website.domain.com:15000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://website.domain.com:15000/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you are sending ```suport.js``` file, it is not html file so how it will render

Comment: have rendered it through httpd

Comment: What is inside suport.js, does it contains html???

Comment: have initialize apple map into this and calculated source and destination. Basically it has js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mccarthy-s7cmi?file=/src/index.js hope it will be clear